# Setting position of image in toolbar in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have a logo in my toolbar, but there is too much space above the logo and almost no space below it. I want to position it exactly in between(with equal space above and below the logo) .

When I use the following code, the app crashes:

```
mToolbar.setLayoutParams(new Toolbar.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL ));
        mToolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.img_logo1);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

How do I position my logo exactly in between the toolbar both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: Use custom toolbar with imageview

Answer (score 0):

// use custom toolbar layout like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="@color/gray"
   app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
   app:contentInsetRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
   android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
   android:padding="0dp"
  app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar_backbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_back"
        android:visibility="visible"
       />

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/title_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_36pt"
        android:text="Title"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment the code you are using in `Activity` and In your`xml` Please add `ImageView` inside `Toolbar`. Please see below code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:visibility="visible"
                />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Hop this will help**